# Absolute value inequality explanation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

I was solving the inequality $-4 \le \left|\frac {x+4} {2-x} \right| \le 4$ and I first wrote the domain, which is $(-\infty,-4] \cup (-4,2) \cup (2, \infty)$ and I got the solution that $x \le \frac 4 5$ and that $x \ge 4$, however the difference was my answer was $x \in (-4, \frac 4 5] \cup [4, \infty)$ but the correct answer is $x \in (-\infty, \frac 4 5] \cup [4, \infty)$.

Since the domain was defined as $(-4,2)$ for $x \le \frac 4 5$, how come the answer includes $-\infty$ which is outside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stated domain of $(-\infty,-4] \cup (-4,2) \cup (2, \infty)$  is not correct.

The only problematic value of $x$ in the middle expression is one that makes the denominator of the fraction $x-2$ equal to zero. In other words, the domain is $\Bbb R-\{2\}$, which in interval notation is

$$(-\infty,2) \cup (2,\infty)$$

The value of $-4$ is not a problem: it just makes the expression equal to zero, which is perfectly well defined--it fact, it even satisfies the inequality.

So the given correct answer $x \in (-\infty, \frac 4 5] \cup [4, \infty)$ is correct.

Comment: From my book, the method of solving such inequalities is to first find when the variable is positive or negative by making a sign diagram of the function as (x+4)(2-x) which creates a parabola with the domain stated above. I can see that your solution is correct, but I don't see the method used to obtain it.